# Excel VBA script is failing on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Can anyone tell me why this Excel VBA script is failing?  I am using Excel 2011 for Mac 14.6.2 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.3

I'm getting a runtime error 438 at the line: Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
(Object doesn't support this property or method).

I now understand this:  "Application.Replaceformat does not exist in Macintosh VBA. To get this to work on the Mac, you'll have to do this a different way, like storing the active cell's format attributes and then applying them to the range."

```
Sub RedDiacritics()
  Dim X As Long, Diacritics() As String
  Diacritics = Split(StrConv("ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ", vbUnicode), Chr(0))
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For X = 0 To UBound(Diacritics) - 1
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace Diacritics(X), "", xlPart, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.realgeek.com/forums/replaceformat-426603.html

Comment: How to fix the code given this? -------->> "Application.Replaceformat does not exist in Macintosh VBA. To get this to work on the Mac, you'll have to do this a different way, like storing the active cell's format attributes and then applying them to the range."